# How to make border being behind text? Like this:

Tags: html, css

I need to make text exactly like this

[image]

This means that border should be behind the text. I tried many things and have been searching in the Internet all day.

If you now how, please help me)!

Comment: Did you try shadows yet? You can do amazing things with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The following hopefully fits your needs:

```css
*{
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
      display: relative;
}

.behind {
      height: .75rem;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -1;
      top: 1.4rem;
      border-radius: .375rem;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(201, 157, 201), rgb(110, 202, 224));
}

.container h1 {
      position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<h1>Stack Overflow
<div class="behind"></div>
</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution using a (p) element to store the text and the (::after) element to create the line.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #826CDC, #A45DD5);
  position: relative;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 16px 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 0 30px;
}
.text::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.5;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="text">Leaderboard</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code and change what you want:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div{
background-color:#a65cdb;
text-align:center;
font-family:sans-serif;
padding:5px 10px 0 10px;
color:white;
font-size:3rem;
font-weight:600;
z-index:0;
}
span{
background-color:white;
z-index:1;
padding:12px;
position:relative;
display:block;
border-radius:10px;
opacity:50%;
top:-22px;
margin-bottom:0;
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        LEADERBOARD<span></span>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I only saw your question now. Unfortunately too late. And there are also solutions. I would have done it similarly but without nesting. I prefer less nesting because it is easier to read. That would be my way:

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(147,112,219), rgb(153,50,204));
  height:100vh;  
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;   
}

.container {
  display: relative;
  text-align: center;      
}
.container .title {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;  
}

.underline {
  height: 1.15rem;
  width: 410px;  
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto;  
  top: 2.3rem;
  border-radius: .375rem;
  background-color:white;
  opacity: 30%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title">LEADERBOARD</div>
    <div class="underline"></div>    
  </div>  
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can just use another div and use the z-index property to make it go back of a text.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).